# Scraping paginated website - Accessing page 20+ goes to page 1

Tags: web-scraping

I would like to scrape data within this website: https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-dealers/search?sort=with-retailer-reviews&forSale=on&toOrder=on&postcode=NG15GA&radius=&make=&page=1

However, I cannot go to page 21 when navigating through web browser or programatically - it goes back to page 1 when accessing pass 20.

I am not sure, maybe this is because of the location? Since the website is in UK and I am in Singapore. I am not using any VPN.

What are the things I need to do to navigate above page 20 - also programatically?

Comment: Ask the owner of the website, seems like a problem on their end, this is not something you will be able to fix on your own. Maybe someone from the UK can confirm or deny if location has anything to do.

Answer (score 0):

try the link on the browser first. If you can't access it, that it's not a problem from your code, rather than the website itself.